# Do covariant cv-qualifiers apply to primitive types in C++?

Tags: c++, constants, covariance

In C++ it is valid to reduce the cv-qualifier of a return type in a derived class:

```
class Base {
    virtual const Base* f();
};

class Derived : public Base {
    Base* f() override;
};
```

Is this valid with pointers to primitive types?

```
class Base {
    virtual const int* f();
};

class Derived : public Base {
    int* f() override;
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do covariant cv-qualifiers apply to primitive types in C++?

**NO**

> **§ 10.3.7 Virtual functions**
>
> The return type of an overriding function shall be either identical to the return type of the overridden function or covariant with the classes of the functions. If a function `D::f` overrides a function `B::f`, **the return types of the functions are covariant if they satisfy the following criteria:**
>
> - both are pointers to classes, both are lvalue references to
>     classes, or both are rvalue references to classes
> - the class in the return type of `B::f` is the same class as the class
>     in the return type of `D::f`, or is an unambiguous and accessible
>     direct or indirect base class of the class in the return type of `D::f`
> - both pointers or references have the same cv-qualification and the
>     class type in the return type of `D::f`

Comment: Is there any reason for this not to be valid? Or is this just an oversight?